# Sub-pixel positioning with php

Tags: php, floating-point, gd, subpixel

I'm writing a graphic app in PHP.
I'm using the GD function `imagecopy()` to combine two images, one smaller than the other.
I want to position the smaller image on top of the bigger image in a float point position.
Like this:

```
imagecopy($bg,$front,30.7,15.2,0,0,100,100);
```

The function receives Integers, so my coordinates are automatically being rounded up or down. This is important to me as I'm creating a delicate animation and the rounding of the float values messes it up.
Is there a way to draw the image in it's float point position?

Thank you.

Comment: Those parameters are defined as INT so not with that function

Comment: Images are drawn with pixels on your screen. 0.7 or 0.2 pixel makes no sense as they don't exist. There is no such thing as half a pixel

Comment: @dan do you work with tiny images ? Are you sure you need to be precise at 1/10 of a pixel ? Just that you don't loose your mind on an XY problem.

Comment: Moving images by sub-pixel can create some unwanted blurring, or other anomalies. Unless working with retina images, its best to stick with the 1 to 1 relation of movement.